# How do I make a constructor that assigns multiple parameters?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am really new to java and just trying to get my head around how everything works. I have a method like this:

```
public assignmentmarks(String name, int mark1, int mark2, int mark3)
{

}
```

and the question asks to create the constructor that uses all the fields (courseName, assignment1, assignment2, assignment3)

**This is what I have tried**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class assignmentmarks {

     private String courseName;
     private int assignment1;
     private int assignment2;
     private int assignment3;
     int average;
     int mark;

     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void AssignmentMarks(String name, int mark1, int mark2, int mark3)
    {
        assignment1 = mark1;
        assignment2 = mark2;
        assignment3 = mark3;
        courseName = name;

        AssignmentMarks assignmentMarks = new AssignmentMarks(mark1, mark2, mark3, name);
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest you look at Java OOP tutorials online [like this one from tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm) to get a better grasp on using constructors and member variables in Java objects.

Comment: You have some syntax errors in your code, please show the full class (i.e. copy and paste the entire file this code is in), as there are likely some errors in the structure, not just the logic

Comment: Ive updated it and put in my entire code

Comment: the constructor of an instance is called after the instance is created to initialize it, you do not need to create the instance - actually you are creating a new instance as part of initialization of the previous one - that new instance will also execute the constructor, also creating a new instance, which again will create another new instance... and again... that is, infinite instances will be created (or Out Of Memory) - or is the last statement just in the wrong block?!

Answer (score 2):

> I have a method like this:
>
> ```
> public assignmentmarks(String name, int mark1, int mark2, int mark3)
> {
>
> }
> ```

That is not a method.  It is a constructor!!

A constructor is a "method-like thing" that has no return type, and the same name as the enclosing class.

All you need to do is add some statements that will assign the parameters to the fields of your class.

---

Having said that, `assignmentmarks` is a bad choice for a class name.  The Java style rules say that a class name should:

1. Start with a capital letter
2. Use camel case; i.e. each embedded word should start with a capital letter.

Thus ... `AssignmentMarks` would be a better name.

(Yes ... this kind of stuff really does matter.  Conforming to standard style makes your code readable, which makes it more maintainable, which will save you and your future colleagues time and hair-tearing.)

---

Also note the names (identifiers) in Java are case sensitive.  So you need to be *consistent*.  Don't use `assignmentmarks` in one place and `AssignmentMarks` in another.  That is likely to lead to compilation errors ... or worse.

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to go around that.
Firstly the thing you aimed to create is called an "All-arguments-constructor" meaning you want to have a declared way to create an instance(entity) of a class and while doing so you want to have all properties(fields\parameters) of it filled with values specified on the call of the said constructor.
There is a hack way to do so using [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) and just annotating your class with `@AllArgsConstructor`, but I recommend you continue learning how those things are made by hand and then revisit mentioned syntaxis sugar later.
With that being said you want to create something like a method that neither has return type nor "void" written in its signature, then refers to every property(field\parameter) of an instance trough `this` (which literally means "I want to work with *this* particular entity") and then assigns them values that you passed through constructor.
In your case, it would look like that:

```
// We have passed all the values that we need trough constructor.
    public AssignmentMarks(String name, int ass1, int ass2, int ass3, int mark, int average) {

    // Now we assign them to the properties of an instance we creating.
    // "courseName" of the created instance becomes "name" we passed.
    this.courseName = name; 

   // "assignment1" of the created instance becomes "ass1" we passed
    this.assignment1 = ass1; 

    // I bet you are getting the hang of it now.
    this.assignment2 = ass2; 

    // And so on.
    this.assignment3 = ass3; 

    // And so forth.
    this.mark = mark; 

    // Until you have assigned values to all properties you want to assign in the constructor.
    this.average = average;
    }
```

Now that you have this constructor you could just simply create a new instance like so:

```
AssignmentMarks instance = new AssignmentMarks("programming", 1, 2, 3, 17, 20);
```

Where we also declared all the values we want to be assigned.

This how you could have done it with lombok:

```
    //This is an entire class
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class AssignmentMarks {

     private String courseName;
     private int assignment1;
     private int assignment2;
     private int assignment3;
     int average;
     int mark;
}
```

Now it already has "All argument constructor" because of `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation.

P.S. I double the previous writer on naming your class in CamelCase it is important.